# If $G$ is nilpotent of class 2 and if $a \in G$, then the function $\alpha: G \rightarrow G$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is nilpotent of class 2 and if $a \in G$, then the function $\alpha: G \rightarrow G$ defined by $x \rightarrow [a,x]$ is a homomorphism.

Proof: Let $x,y \in G$

Then $\alpha(xy) = [a,xy] = [a,x][a,y]^x$

So if we can show that $[a,y]^x=[a,y]$ then we'll basically have done it.

The fact that $G$ is nilpotent of class 2 will mean that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is abelian.

case 1: $x \in Z(G)$. Then $[a,y]^x=[a,y]$ automatically.

case 2: $x \notin Z(G)$. Then we have

$[a,y]^x$ mod $Z(G)=[a,y]$  mod $Z(G)$

And i'm a bit stuck here it seems.

Comment: An alternative definition of “nilpotent of class $2$” is that $[G,G]$ is contained in $Z(G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $G$ is nilpotent of class 2 precisely means that $[a,y]$ will commute with $x$, which is what you need to complete your proof.

Comment: Hmm, can you lay out the details for me?

Comment: Just because $[G,[G,G]]=\{e\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Or, $G/Z(G)$ is abelian and so $G' \leq Z(G)$.